# Command "&" is not working

Tags: macros, cases

I am new to TeX and I am trying to write the following

```
\begin{equation}
N_{a,0}\begin{cases}
R_{0,0} & a=0\\
N_{a-1,0}e^{-m} & 1\leq a\leq a_{max}-1\\
N_{a-1,0}e^{-m}/1-e^{-m} & a=a_{max}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

but I get an error because `&` is not being recognized as a command, it does not even have the green color as the rest of the commands do. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Please tell us which error it is. And indent your code by 4 spaces so we can see the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your document?

Comment: I did't... I've added it and now it works!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @egreg would you add this as an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether `&` is recognized as a command as far as syntax coloring is concerned depends on the editor you're using.

In any case, in order to use the `cases` environment you need to load `amsmath.`

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
N_{a,0}=
\begin{cases}
  R_{0,0} & a=0\\
  N_{a-1,0}e^{-m} & 1\leq a\leq a_{\max}-1\\
  N_{a-1,0}e^{-m}/1-e^{-m} & a=a_{\max}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note `\max` to get the letters upright.

[image]

Here's what I get in the editor I use most commonly (Aquamacs)

[image]

This is how TeXStudio colorizes the same input:

[image]